# Cant use control's dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have my custom control named "FileSelectDialog" with Dependency Property:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FilePathProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("FilePath", typeof(string), typeof(FileSelectDialog));

    public string FilePath
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FilePathProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FilePathProperty, value); }
    }
```

Then I'm trying to bind to this dependency property like this:

```
    <controls:FileSelectDialog FilePath="{Binding FolderName}"/>
```

But nothing happing, no initial text shown in my control, no updated text's saving to 'FolderName' property! I got such error in Output window:

```
    System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'FolderName' property not found on 'object' ''FileSelectDialog' (Name='FolderSelector')'. BindingExpression:Path=FolderName; DataItem='FileSelectDialog' (Name='FolderSelector'); target element is 'FileSelectDialog' (Name='FolderSelector'); target property is 'FilePath' (type 'String')
```

So, as far as I understand, control try to find property 'FolderName on itself, while it must look for it in parents control DataContext. For example, when I use simple textbox:

```
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FolderName}"/>
```

All is working fine.

Comment: So, solution is:
                        <controls:FileSelectDialog x:Name="FolderSelector" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  
                        FilePath="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=DataContext.FolderName}"
                                           />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems a basic DataContext issue to me
How did you set the DataContext of your FileSelectDialog Control ? seems you set the dataContext in code as 'Me'/'this' or in xaml with 'RelativeSource Self' or something like this.

Comment: You were right! I am setting DataContext in my custom control constructor to this, as soon as I want to get access to code behind properties from control's xaml.
So, I have to change code, which is using control to use another element DataContext.

Answer (score 1):

> no initial text shown in my control

I understand you are exposing this property in a custom control, but are you updating some of the control in your customcontrol with the value set in your dependency property?

You may need to attach a callback and show the value set in your DP in some control in your customcontrol.

Like:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FilePathProperty =           DependencyProperty.Register("FilePath", typeof(string), typeof(FileSelectDialog),  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None,HandleFilePathPropertyChanged));

    private static void HandleFilePathPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control= (FileSelectDialog)d;
        control.SomeUIControl.Text= (string)e.NewValue;
    }
```

If already doing this, then the second problem is the error shown in Binding. For this try setting the DataContext of your control to the object which has the source property.

```
    <controls:FileSelectDialog x:Name="customControl" FilePath="{Binding FolderName}"/> 
   ... code-behind.
     customControl.DataContext = sourceObject.
```

Comment: Yes, I am updating my custom control with value from DP and all is working fine.
I've tried this:
codebehind:
            {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContextChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(_DataContextChanged);
        }

        void _DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            FolderSelector.DataContext = DataContext;
        }
But it doesnt helped - binding failed before datacontext of control's parent updated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to witre the property changed call back function

```
   public static readonly DependencyProperty FilePathProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("FilePath", typeof(string), 
typeof(FileSelectDialog),new UIPropertyMetadata(
                new PropertyChangedCallback(PropertyChanged))); 


private static void PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d,    
     DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)       
    {           
        //Do your Stuff       
    }
```